# Screen rotation inside app in Qt 5.3

Tags: qt, embedded, qt5

Does any one know what is the equivalent way of Qt4 QWS setTransformation in Qt 5.3? I am looking for a way to rotate the screen dynamically inside the app. Below is the way I launch the app:

```
./MyApp -platform linuxfb -plugin tslib
```

I am searching the net for a while but no luck with the solution of it. Any suggestion or clue on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using widgets or qml?

Comment: Widgets. Sorry for not saying this.